# Perform replacement in nested predicate using recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to write a set of predicates that replace terms in nested predicates using recursion; i.e.

Given:

```
r(a, aa).
r(c, cc).
r(e, ee).
p(a, b, c).
p(a, b, p(d, e, f)).
p(a, p(p(b, c, d), e, f), g).
```

I want:

```
p(aa, b, cc)
p(aa, b, p(d, ee, f))
p(aa, p(p(b, cc, d), ee, f), g)
```

Here is a (probably wildly incorrect) attempt:

```
inf(p(A, B, C), p(AA, BB, CC)):-
    p(A, B, C),
    (   r(A, AA);
        r(B, BB);
        r(C, CC)
    ).
inf(p(A, B, C), p(AA, BB, CC)):-
    p(A, B, C),
    (   r(A, AA);
        r(B, BB);
        r(C, CC)
    ),
    (   inf(A, AA);
        inf(B, BB);
        inf(C, CC)
    ).
```

With a call to `inf(X, Y).` this yields:

```
X = p(a, b, c),
Y = p(aa, _1262, _1264)
X = p(a, b, c),
Y = p(_1064, _1066, cc)
X = p(a, b, p(d, e, f)),
Y = p(aa, _1074, _1076)
X = p(a, p(p(b, c, d), e, f), g),
Y = p(aa, _1082, _1084)
false
```

which is not what I want. I suspect there is something wrong with how my base case combines with the code doing replacements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks/JC

Comment: If you're dealing with an arbitrary level of compound terms `p`, then you could use `(=..)/2` to get the list equivalent. `p(a, b, p(d, e, f)) =.. L` --> `L = [p, a, b, p(d, e, f)]`. This allows you to use recursive list processing which gets you the generalization you need to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified approach which might have some exception cases for you to examine and explore, but it illustrates a handy use of `(=..)/2` and `maplist/3`. `(=..)/2` provides an equivalence between a term and a list (*e.g.*, `p(a, b, p(d, e, f)) =.. L` results in `L = [p, a, b, p(d, e, f)]` and `Term =.. [foo, x, y]` results in `Term = foo(x, y)`). By getting a list equivalent of a term, you can use recursive list processing to handle arbitrary compound terms.

`maplist(foo, List1, List2)` exercises a query `foo(X1, X2)` for every corresponding element `X1` of `List1` and `X2` of `List2` and succeeds if each query succeeds and provides argument instantiations for each success as Prolog normally does on a query.

You can use `maplist(r, TermList, SubList)` to perform a simple substitution using the mapping `r` as long as `r` succeeds for every element of the list. However, in this case, you'd want a mapping that succeeds with the same term back again if there is no mapping. For this, you can define `map_r` as below.

```
% map_r is the mapping defined by 'r', or term maps to itself
map_r(X, M) :-
    r(X, M).
map_r(X, X) :-
    \+ r(X, _).

% A functor on its own is just itself after term substitution
term_subst(Term, Functor) :-
    Term =.. [Functor].  % Term has no arguments

% A functor with arguments is the same functor with args substituted
term_subst(Term, TermSub) :-
    Term =.. [Functor | [Arg|Args]],       % Term has at least one arg
    maplist(map_r, [Arg|Args], ArgsMap),   % mapping of matching args
    maplist(term_subst, ArgsMap, ArgsSub), % recursive substitution for sub-terms
    TermSub =.. [Functor | ArgsSub].
```

Comment: Thank you lurker! This seems to be the way to go.